# Populate TextView with different strings for different levels

Tags: java, android, xml, textview, populate

I'm making a quiz game and for each level there is a textview for the question and a text field for you to type your answer. There's going to be a lot of levels, so instead of having tons and tons of Java classes and XML files I was wondering if there is a quicker solution to this?

I was thinking of having one Java class that populates the same TextView with different strings for different levels. Is this possible? I think I may have to use a database?

The code that I have at the moment is something like this (XML):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="fill_horizontal"
android:layout_margin="25dp"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tutorialWelcome"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="@string/tutorial_step_four_a"
    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/enterButton"
    android:hint="@string/answerhere"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tutorialWelcome"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="@string/tutorial_step_four_b"
    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/enterButton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/nextbutton"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_send_now" 
    style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"/>
```

Any help would be grateful!

Comment: Seems like you need to create custom view.
and public function / constructor to set the text for the text view

Comment: How are you writing a trivia game, without already using a database?! O_o - Yes, DB it up. Have some custom classes that represent db structure and just call: <code>textView.setText(myObj.getQuestionText(iLevelNum);</code> or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

There are few options:

- store your questions in strings.xml, then use getString(R.string.id_of_question_you_want) to fetch the question and later display it
- store the questions in SQLite database
- store the questions in a file, and you will need to write functions to read the file

EDIT:

You can also use string array in xml, and then based on which questin is currently being displayed, populate from the array, eg:

- have your quesitons.xml where you define your array of questions:

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <resources>
      <string-array name="questions_array">
          <item>Question 1 content</item>
          <item>Question 2 content</item>
          <item>Question 3 content</item>
          <item>Question 4 content</item>
      </string-array>
  </resources>
  ```
- in your activity, you can get these questions in an array:

  ```
  Resources res = getResources();
  String[] questions = res.getStringArray(R.array.questions_array);
  ```
- then, keep track of which question should be displayed now, and get the string from array in your activity that populates the layout:

  ```
  int questionNumber = 5;

  textViewQuestion.setText(questions[questionNumber]);
  ```

Just remember to check for boundaries, otherwise you'll get an exception if your questionNumber is higher than the number of questions in an array. Remember that arrays in Java start from index 0.

and probably some other...

Check [the docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) for info about storing data.

Comment: This makes sense. Although I'm slightly confused. Do you think I would need a bunch of "if" statements to set the condition? For example, if this is level one, use level one question? If so, how do you think I could implement that.

Comment: Another - maybe more useful - option would be to store questions in an array in xml file. See my updated answer. Then in your activity you can use an index to get the correct question from an array.